# Programmatically opening device settings page for data roaming

Tags: android, dual-sim

In a dual SIM phone, generally the data roaming option is available in Settings > Data Usage and on a dual SIM settings page. Is it possible to programatically open it?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Also, read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS) for some caveats.

Comment: It open Mobile network settings page but Data Roaming option is not available at there.It is available in Dual SIM Settings page or Data Usage Setting page

Comment: It might varies from Android version to version. Have you tested my codes on all versions of Android from 2.1 to 4.4 to see what you get?

Comment: I am already using the same but the problem is Android Versions.

Comment: Is there Any way to Find Action String for this.

Comment: You might try looking at Android source codes from API 7 to 19 and try Reflection to execute the required method. I don't remember where I saw the method in the source codes. Sorry.

Comment: FYI: In the future, please do not double post (Your other post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641705/android-how-to-open-dual-sim-settings-page?rq=1)) as you will get a lot of negative downvotes - it will decrease your reputation :)